# Javascript Replace Text in tags without changing children element HTML and Content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script where I'd like to recolocar the text anywhere in the body visible to the user like so:

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/replaced word/g,'HELLO'));
```

This works but it works to well. Whenever "replaced word" is within a tag, like a href, or span, or div, or anything it throws off all the formatting on the page. What is the best way to accomplish replacing the text for every occurrence in the page, no matter what element it's in, without effecting the page's functionality? Thanks

EDIT: Thanks to talsibony and everyone's help I have an answer on how to replace words in child elements not effecting the html tags. I'd like to have the replacement with a font color or other styling options like so:

```
$(element).html($(element).selectorText().replace(/thisi/g,'<abbr title="hover title"><font color="#10a9cf">HELLO</font></abbr>'));
```

The weird thing is this code works in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ozoxxq1/1/) but when I include this in the google chrome extension I'm working on and the page loads the page is empty. When I switch it back to selectortext it loads but I see the html tags in the replacement.

I can't understand why because a staright replace doesn't work and doesn't let the page load either!

```
$(element).html($(element).selectorText().replace(/thisi/g,'HELLO'));
```

In the console I get the following error: **Cannot read property 'replace' of null**

What am I missing here? Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like you will have to run a loop on all body elements.. then use the replace on each one of them unless someone else know better way...

Comment: Why not put the want-to-replace-word in a span or another element. Then change the value of that element. Otherwise, you would need to loop though all the elements and change the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I think you will have to do it is in each element individually 
and use this jquery small plugin I rewrite here is the code and also

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ozoxxq1/)

**the html**

```
<div id="parent">
    thisi sthe fpcd
    <p>p</p>
</div>
```

**plugin to find the content of the selector text without child elements**

```
$.fn.selectorText = function(text) {
    var str = '';

    this.contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType === 3) {
            if(text){
                this.textContent = text;
                return false;
            }else{
                str += this.textContent || this.innerText || '';
            }

        }
    });

    return str;
};
```

**using it for your case**

```
allowReplaceTags = ['DIV'];
$('body').find('*').each(function (i, element) {
    if ($.inArray(allowReplaceTags,element.tagName)){
        // do replace
        $(element).selectorText($(element).selectorText().replace(/thisi/g,'HELO'));

    }

});
```

Comment: Can I leave it as "element" like you have it or do I have to specify the elements it needs to iterate through?

Comment: And what would then be the best method or replacing? Sorry, javascript is not my forte. Thanks

Comment: I think it is more complicated the this answers because there could be childs inside this p that we don't want to replace, so maybe need to get last child first and climb in parents

Comment: Thank you! That works great!! One other question - how do I keep html tags within the replace? Say, to make the replaced word a different color.

Comment: you welcome, regards to your second question create fiddle example and I will try to help with it

Comment: You're the best! You can see what I'm trying to do here https://jsfiddle.net/6ozoxxq1/1/. The html tags come out as plain text.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6ozoxxq1/1/ all you had to do is to change the $(element).selectorText to $(element).html so it will know it gets html content and not text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81230/discussion-between-buster-and-talsibony).

Answer (score -1):

$("body").html($("body").text().replace(/replaced word/g,'HELLO'));

Comment: That looks like it would strip out all HTML tags.

Comment: it will change the whole HTML

Comment: Yea that rendered the entire page as source code. With the word replaced though.